# How to write data to a new line using Files.createFile()?

Tags: java

```
java.nio.file.Path newfile = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/home/krishnaprasad/report.json");
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-------");
    FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attrs = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms);
    if(!Files.exists(newfile)) {
        Files.createFile(newfile, attrs);
    }

    Files.write(newfile, jsonarr.toString().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

I'm append the JSONArray to the file. It is appending in the same line. Can I append it in the next line?

Comment: You don't. `Files.createNewFile()` doesn't do any output, and in fact both the `exists()` and `createNewFile()` calls here are completely pointless and wasteful.

Comment: Any other way we can handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a newline before the JSON:

```
String content = System.lineSeparator() + jsonarr;

Files.write(newfile, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```